# Akka and Docker on Marathon

Tags: playframework, docker, akka, mesosphere, marathon

I have a setup on Mesosphere that uses Marathon to deploy Docker applications.
Now each of the Docker applications is a Play application that relies heavily on Akka remoting.

What Marathon does with Mesos DNS is that it assigns an internal DNS address to each `cluster` of tasks.

Now, for a two of the docker containers, here's my situation:
Task ID: `task-A`
Task DNS: `task-A.mesosphere.mesos`
Akka remoting configuration:

```
app {
  host = ${?APP_HOST}
  akka {
    port = 11112
  }
}
akka {
  jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = false
  log-dead-letters = 0
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = ${?app.host}
      port = ${?app.akka.port}
    }
  }
}
```

Now the docker container of the application is launched with ports `9000` & `11112` open on both sides:
`docker run -p 11112:11112 -h task-A.marathon.mesos ...`

Similarly, for Task-B:
Task ID: `task-A`
Task DNS: `task-A.mesosphere.mesos`
Akka remoting configuration:

```
app {
  host = ${?APP_HOST}
  akka {
    port = 11120
  }
}
akka {
  jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = false
  log-dead-letters = 0
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = ${?app.host}
      port = ${?app.akka.port}
    }
  }
}
```

Now the docker container of the application is launched with port `11120` open on both sides:
`docker run -p 11120:11120 -h task-B.marathon.mesos ...`

Now the problem is that I cannot get the two tasks to communicate with each other via Akka.
For example, if there's an ask from Task-B, I get exceptions:
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://application@task-A.marathon.mesos:11112/), Path(/user/CoreMaster)]] after [15000 ms]]]

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What is akka version? I guess you need to set bind-hostname config and in order to it work you need to update akka version to 2.4-SNAPSHOT.